# Creating Heatmap from attribute value of point features in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, heat-map

I've run through tutorial from ArcGIS on how to create a heat map using Spatial Analysis.

Based on the example, point features are scattered around the map and we need do the following to generate heat map.

Run Project Data -> Aggregate Data -> Collect Events -> Run "Hotspot Analysis" ->  Run "Spatial Analysis"

Is it possible to generate a heat map if I don't have point features that are scattered around the map but instead I have point features that have an attribute value that represent "Number of point" around this point features?

For example: I have 5 locations.

In the first scenario, I will have

1. 5 points feature around area #1
2. 20 points feature around area #2
3. 40 points feature around area #3
4. 30 points feature around area #4
5. 10 points feature around area #5

While for second scenario, I will have

1. Point feature 1, attribute value: 5
2. Point feature 2, attribute value: 20
3. Point feature 3, attribute value: 40
4. Point feature 4, attribute value: 30
5. Point feature 5, attribute value: 10

Comment: How did you got this result?I mean how are you showing your data i.e. symbology classification etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve the heat map I'm looking for using Kernel Density (Spatial Analysis) and use the respective attribute as a value for "Population Field".

[image]